# Internal server error using Swiftmailer on Silex

Tags: php, swiftmailer, silex

I'm working on a Silex project and I'm trying to send an email using the Swiftmailer provider but always get an internal server error(500).

Registering:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SwiftmailerServiceProvider(), array(
        'swiftmailer.options' => array(
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => '465',
            'username' => 'my_email',
            'password' => 'my_password')

    ));
```

If I call the mailer $app['mailer'] throw an internal server error.

If I try with the documentation example I got an internal server error:

```
 $app->post('/feedback', function () use ($app) {
    $request = $app['request'];

    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('[YourSite] Feedback')
        ->setFrom(array('noreply@yoursite.com'))
        ->setTo(array('feedback@yoursite.com'))
        ->setBody($request->get('message'));

    $app['mailer']->send($message);

    return new Response('Thank you for your feedback!', 201);
});
```

I don't know what's the problem, I have no troubles with the other providers.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, what's the error? Check your webserver's logs.

Comment: You can set `$app["debug"]` to true to get a detailed error message and a stack trace.

Comment: maybe you'll find a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34033427/5628225

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to add the following entries in your 'swiftmailer.options' array? Gmail by default uses ssl on port 465.

```
'encryption' => 'ssl',
'auth_mode' => 'login',
```

[**Update**]
If you define namespace in your code, need to add '\' in front of Silex\Provider..

```
$this->register(new Silex\Provider\SwiftmailerServiceProvider(), array(
```

to

```
$this->register(new \Silex\Provider\SwiftmailerServiceProvider(), array(
```

Comment: I checked but it is the same, always throw ERROR 500

Comment: In sliex, you can catch the error using $app->error(function() {...}). Could you dump the stack trace using $e->getTraceAsString()?

Comment: How about changing host name from smtp.google.com to smtp.googlemail.com? Someone said in certain country the latter one is used.

Comment: Neither, if I call Swiftmailer always crash, does not matter where I put the code

Comment: Do you define your own namespace in your code? If yes, you need to put '\' in front of Silex\Provider...