# How to handle Swift_TransportException in Silex

Tags: php, swiftmailer, silex

I'm having quiet weird problem with catching SwiftMailer's exceptions in Silex. I want to send an email like this:

```
try {
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('subject')
        ->setFrom(array('form'))
        ->setTo(array('to'))
        ->setBody('body');
    $app['mailer']->send($message);
} catch (\Swift_TransportException $e) {
    $app['logger']->addError('Unable to send welcome email');
}
```

I know it's not going to send any email on localhost and I'm expecting it to fail but why I can't catch the `Swift_TransportException` exception in `try - catch` block?

It just prints:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host localhost [Connection refused #61]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Emails are not sent immediately when you call `send()`, instead they get into a memory spool that is flushed during the application shutdown, when the response has already been sent. This improves the user experience, as the response can be sent much faster.

Comment: Create an application-level error handler for swift exceptions http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#error-handlers

Comment: I'm using error handler already but it doesn't catch this exception. Even if it did, it wouldn't solve my problem, because I don't want to show error page when Swift can't send an email.

Comment: Creating an error handler for `\Swift_TransportException` should catch it and if you have an empty function there it should swallow the exception silently.

Answer (score 0):

i had trouble sending mails on my localhost too -
i got rid of the exception with this code:

```
/// config
$app['swiftmailer.options'] = array(
    'host' => 'smtp.1und1.de',
    'port' => '465',
    'username' => 'xxx',
    'password' => 'yyy',
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'auth' => 'login',
);

// bootstrap
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SwiftmailerServiceProvider(), array(
    'swiftmailer.options' => $app['swiftmailer.options']
));
```